# Cannot find enough owners to sign. 1 missing

Tags: safe-core

I've loaded two signers using the load_cli_owners command. However it keeps giving me this error "Cannot find enough owners to sign. 1 missing".

This is on opbnb. Any idea for the cause?

Comment: This seems to be either a bug with the CLI or an issue with the deployed proxy contract at 0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2

Comment: Have you made sure you used the correct syntax for casting this command?
`load_cli_owners <account_private_key>` or `export MY_PRIVATE_KEY=YOUR_EOA_PRIVATE_KEY` and then `load_cli_owners MY_PRIVATE_KEY` ?

Comment: Yes I've made sure of that, I've also replicated the same commands for my Safe on Mainnet and Arbitrum and they both work, just not opBnb

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the CLI with [`tx-service`](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-cli/tree/main?tab=readme-ov-file#modes) mode on, this will not work as our Transaction Service [does not currently support](https://docs.safe.global/advanced/api-supported-networks) opBNB.

Hope it helps; best, Louis

Comment: We are working with Safe contracts version 1.3.0, and I don't currently have Txn mode on

Comment: Is it possible to look into this?